# java android Q read ip from hotspot /proc/net/arp: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: java, android, android-10.0

I want to read IPs which are connected to my hotspot only on Android Q I have a problem: 
This is a log:

```java
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/arp: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

And here is what not work:

```java
 br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/net/arp"));
```

I add to manifest:

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

Add all permission are granted also I add:

```java
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    if (Settings.System.canWrite(ListOfTerminalsActivity.this)) {
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        try {
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ignored) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: @Manzotin yes I did

Comment: Do you mind to share it please?

Comment: @Manzotin yes  I share

Answer (score 1):

Android 10 onwards accessing "/proc/net/arp" is not allowed. For more info refer [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#proc-net-filesystem)

Answer (score 0):

```java
Pattern macPattern = Pattern.compile("..:..:..:..:..:..");

BufferedReader br = null;
try {
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    Process ipProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(IP_CMD);
    ipProc.waitFor();
    if (ipProc.exitValue() != 0) {
      throw new Exception("Unable to access ARP entries");
    }

    br = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(ipProc.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      String[] neighborLine = line.split("\\s+");
      if (neighborLine.length <= 4) {
        continue;
      }
      String ip = neighborLine[0];
      final String hwAddr = neighborLine[4];

      InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
      if (addr.isLinkLocalAddress() || addr.isLoopbackAddress()) {
        continue;
      }
      String macAddress = neighborLine[4];
      String state = neighborLine[neighborLine.length - 1];

      if (!NEIGHBOR_FAILED.equals(state)
          && !NEIGHBOR_INCOMPLETE.equals(state)) {
        boolean isReachable = false;
        try {
          isReachable = InetAddress.getByName(ip).isReachable(5000);
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (isReachable) {
          result.add(new WifiClient(ip, hwAddr));
        }
      }
    }
  } else {
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/net/arp"));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      String[] parts = line.split(" +");
      if (parts.length < 6) {
        continue;
      }
      final String ipAddr = parts[0];
      final String hwAddr = parts[3];
      if (!ipAddr.equalsIgnoreCase("IP")) {
        boolean isReachable = false;
        try {
          isReachable = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddr).isReachable(5000);
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (isReachable) {
          result.add(new WifiClient(ipAddr, hwAddr));
        }
      }
    }
  }
} catch (Exception e) {
} finally {
  try {
    if (br != null) {
      br.close();
    }
  } catch (IOException e) {
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of IP_CMD at line 7?

Comment: @Manzotin     private static final String IP_CMD = "ip neighbor";

Comment: In my Android 11, i received this erro: Cannot bind netlink socket: Permission denied

Comment: "java.lang.Exception: Unable to access ARP entries"

throw such an exception after running the "ip neighbor" command.

Comment: @MizaelMontenegro same issue here https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/248314/